# Как определить почему происходит ROLLBACK?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 42
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"42", "product_id"=>"1"}
  Cart Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `carts`.* FROM `carts` WHERE `carts`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  LineItem Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `line_items`.* FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`cart_id` = 1 AND `line_items`.`product_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering line_items/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered line_items/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered line_items/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
  LineItem Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`cart_id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  LineItem Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `line_items`.* FROM `line_items` WHERE `line_items`.`cart_id` = 1
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `products`.* FROM `products` WHERE `products`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered collection of line_items/_line_item.html.erb [1 times] (1.9ms)
  Rendered carts/_cart.html.erb (4.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 71ms (Views: 60.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Появляется при добавлении в модель `line_item` строчки `belongs_to :order`.

Comment: Взять отладчик и посмотреть в `errors` модели?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия Rails - пятая? В ней связи `belongs_to` стали по-умолчанию обязательны. Если при создании объекта не указать для него все подобные ассоциации - рельса не создаст объект. У вас видно, что передается только `product_id`, а `order_id` нет. Возможно, это и является причиной.

Если связь с заказом у вас необязательна, вы можете указать это в файле модели:

```
belongs_to :order, optional: true
```

Тогда объект будет создаваться и без указания `order_id`.

Comment: Ага, пятая. "У вас видно, что передается только product_id, а order_id нет." можно подробнее про это?

Comment: `Started POST "/line_items?product_id=1"` и ниже `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"42", "product_id"=>"1"}`. `POST` на `/line_items` - создание нового ресурса (`line_items#create`), в данных кроме токена (нужен для безопасности) - видно только `product_id`. Но `belongs_to :order` у вас обязательна, значит нужно передать еще `order_id`, либо указать его прям в экшне `line_items#create`

Comment: Еще, почему `line_item` создается, если не передается `cart_id`, хотя в модели есть строчка `belongs_to :cart`. Создается `line_item` так `@line_item = @cart.add_product(product)`. В методе `add_product` - `line_items.build(product_id: product.id)`.

Comment: При таком варианте создания к объекту line_item автоматически привязывается @cart, и условие по обязательному указанию связи с cart выполняется

Comment: А как именно оно привязывается?